# range(n)[x:y:z]

Tags: python, range, python-2.x

Not sure what the arguments inside the `[ ]` really do after the `range()` function.

Exp: `print ( range(5)[::-2])`
Output: `[4, 2, 0]`

But if `[x:y:z]` stands for `[start:stop:step]`, then when I put `print(range(5)[4:-2:-2])`, the output list is `[4]` instead of `[4, 2, 0]`, not sure how that works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, `range()` creates a special `range` object. In Python 2, it creates a `list`.

```
List element:     0  1  2  3  4
Index:            0  1  2  3  4
Backwards index: -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

So, going from index `4` to index `-2` really goes from list element `4` to list element `3`. Since you're skipping every other element, you don't get to `3`, leaving you with merely `[4]`.

Comment: Then how can i go till negative number

Comment: @VigneshKalai There’s no negative number in the range. If you want negative numbers, you shouldn’t tell `range` to go from zero to a certain (positive) number.

Comment: As @Shashank says, create that `list` by passing the proper arguments to `range()` rather than by attempting to slice an improper `list` into shape.

Comment: but `range(5)[4:-2]` results `[]`. Then how `range(5)[4:-2:-2]` results `[4]` ?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 `range(4, -1, -2)` is a lot more annoying to type than `range(5)[::-2]` though.

Answer (score 7):

You’re right, it’s `[start:stop:step]`. Note that negative starts and stops are defined to start at the end of the sequence. So for a range that ends with the values `2, 3, 4`, the stop `-2` refers to the `3` (-1 is the last, -2 is the second to last, etc.).

So in your case, the range has a length of 5, starting at 0 and ending at 4. You start at the index 4, and end at the index -2 which is `5-2 = 3`. So so far, the index refers to `[3, 4]`. Now, starting at 4, you have a negative step of 2. So you skip over the 3, resulting in just `[4]`.

If you want `[4, 2, 0]`, then you should leave out the stop:

```
>>> range(5)[4::-2]
[4, 2, 0]
```

You can actually even leave out the start:

```
>>> range(5)[::-2]
[4, 2, 0]
```

---

> but `range(5)[4:-2]` results `[]`. Then how `range(5)[4:-2:-2]` results `[4]`?

The slice is evaluated at once, not one argument after another:

After evaluating the negative stop, `range(5)[4:-2]` is equivalent to `range(5)[4:3]`. Since there is no step specified, the default step of positive 1 will be used. This means that the slice would have to go from index 4 to index 3 with a positive step. That’s impossible, so an empty list is returned.

When we have a negative step, it looks like this: `range(5)[4:3:-2]`. Now, since we have a negative step, the direction is reversed. So we can start at an index 4 and go to a lower index 3.

It’s just defined that for a positive step, `stop >= start` needs to be true, and for a negative step the inverse, `stop <= start`.

Comment: but `range(5)[4:-2]` results `[]`. Then how `range(5)[4:-2:-2]` results `[4]` ?

Comment: @itzmeontv Added a reply to that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Slices with three arguments defined in terms of `[start:stop:step]`. Coincidentally, that's also how range objects are defined with three arguments. We'll see how that comes into play soon.

What you are doing is this:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(5)[4:-2:-2]
[4]
```

Negative indices in Python wrap around from the length of the sequence. So the length of your list is 5, and then you go two steps down with -2, so you get index 3 as your stop value. In other words, index 3 is the sentinel value for the iterator at which point, the slice operation will stop collecting elements. You'll be stepping down 2 indices every step, but index 3 is the sentinel, so the slice stops collecting elements after it grabs the element at index 4 and reaches the stop index.

What you probably actually want to do is this:

```
>>> range(4, -2, -2)
[4, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can treat [x:y:z] stands for [start:stop:jumps] in the range of 5 it will iterate over 0-4 both inclusive and since your z is negative it will iterate from 4 to 0 with 2 jumps 4---3---2(--- represents jumps)so the output is 
4---(3)---2---(1)---0 .
  ------>   ------->

Happy Coding